# I am not able to find the .exe file in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create a c++ blank project
I am not able to find the .exe file in the debug folder.
Where can I find it or should I search in a new directory or should I do something else?
Pls help.
Thanks

Comment: check the build output

Comment: Have you compiled your code? Did it compile successfully? Are you building an .exe or .dll?

Answer (score 1):

you dont have any exe nor debug or release folder until you build the project you are working on...

after that you will find folders Debug or Release depending on what you did

[image]

and inside is the exe generated by VS[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, write a program in the blank project then **build** your project, a debug/Release (based on the mode you select) folder will be created inside `bin` folder which is present in the same directory as the .sln (solution) file.

You can find the **.exe** file inside the debug/Release folder.